# Twilio - Use global variable in a call

Tags: twilio

We can deliver a variable to the function by TwiML, but it's have size/length limit. So I have to save this variable to global, so I can get this variable in anywhere(function) I want. But I'm worry if the variable will be changed by some others, because our function in twilio is serverless. In fact, global variable is not safe.
Anyone can solve this?

Comment: For example, If thousands of people call in a same line, Will global variables still work?

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you are suggesting here?

Comment: I use node.js to develop this. I save a variable to global: global.long_token = response.accessToken. So If I want to get this in another function, I can get from global.

Answer (score 2):

There are no variables in Functions, where state is shared `across` executions as you stated. You will need to use an external datastore for state between executions, if that is a requirement.

Comment: Hi Alan. Yes I can use a datastore to achieve this. But I'm still have some worry: all my function is deployed to twlio, I'm not sure if my variable can be shared in different function, and how does the lifecycle is.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/

Q: How does AWS Lambda isolate my code?

Each AWS Lambda function runs in its own isolated environment, with its own resources and file system view. AWS Lambda uses the same techniques as Amazon EC2 to provide security and separation at the infrastructure and execution levels.